# MongoDB going down again and again

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, multi-tenant

I am using `multi-tenancy` in `mongodb` with `spring-data`, that connects multiple data after `Authentication` by `admin` database. After every some hours the `mongod` services goes down. I am getting following logs while its shutdown:

```
2017-01-17T18:12:45.785+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=32207 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=bystored-staging
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.1
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-01-17T18:12:45.789+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { port: 27017 }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2017-01-17T18:12:45.818+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-01-17T18:12:45.818+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2017-01-17T18:12:45.818+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-01-17T18:12:45.818+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-01-17T18:12:45.818+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=487M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-01-17T18:12:46.050+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-01-17T18:12:46.054+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2017-01-17T18:12:46.055+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-01-17T18:12:46.332+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42522 #1 (1 connection now open)
2017-01-17T18:12:46.333+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:42522 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.4.0-59-generic" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_101-b13" }
2017-01-17T18:12:46.358+0000 I ACCESS   [conn1] Successfully authenticated as principal admin on admin
2017-01-17T18:12:46.360+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42524 #2 (2 connections now open)
2017-01-17T18:12:46.360+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:42524 conn2: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.4.0-59-generic" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_101-b13" }
2017-01-17T18:12:46.394+0000 I ACCESS   [conn2] Successfully authenticated as principal admin on admin
2017-01-17T18:12:54.081+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42546 #3 (3 connections now open)
2017-01-17T18:12:54.082+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:42546 conn3: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.4.0-59-generic" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_101-b13" }
2017-01-17T18:12:54.102+0000 I ACCESS   [conn3] Successfully authenticated as principal admin on admin
2017-01-17T18:17:36.871+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-01-17T18:17:36.871+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-01-17T18:17:36.871+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2017-01-17T18:17:36.871+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 8
2017-01-17T18:17:36.871+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-01-17T18:17:36.871+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-01-17T18:17:36.871+0000 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2017-01-17T18:17:36.874+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2017-01-17T18:17:36.933+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2017-01-17T18:17:36.933+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2017-01-17T18:17:36.933+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
2017-01-17T18:17:36.933+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:0
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to run a background process using `--fork` signal.

Answer (score 0):

> 2017-01-17T18:17:36.871+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got
>   signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends

You got a SIGINT ("got signal 2 (Interrupt)"), this happens when you press CTRL+C to "interrupt" the process. How are you starting the mongod process? Is it running in background?

Comment: Yes, in background using `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf &`. What should be done to fix this?

Comment: Try to use the `--fork` option instead `&`. For instance:  `mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: Is there any difference if I run this as a service?